# how to sort the NSMutableArray in tableview?

Tags: swift

I have a `NSMutableArray` array like below

```
var myArr = NSMutableArray() {
        studentId = 1437404654;
        name = "Rancho";
    },
            {
        studentId = 1932617669;
        name = "Mastora";
    },
            {
        studentId = 1457367179;
        name = "Amanda";
    }
```

i take one more NSMutableArray for sorting

```
var copyArr = NSMutableArray()
@IBOutlet weak var resultTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
var searchActive : Bool = false
```

I am using `myArr` for number of rows count

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myArr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell

let dict = self. myArr[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary       
        cell.idTextField.text = (dict.value(forKey: "studentId") as! String)
        cell.nameTextField.text = (dict.value(forKey: "name") as! String)

  return cell    
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true;
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar){
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {       
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR %K CONTAINS[cd] %@", "studentId", searchText, "name", searchText)

    let sorted = copyArr.filter({
        return predicate.evaluate(with: $0)
    })

    print(sorted)

    myArr.removeAllObjects()

    if sorted.count==0
    {
        myArr.addObjects(from: copyArr as! [Any])
    }
    else {
        myArr.addObjects(from: sorted)
    }

    resultTable.reloadData()
}
```

But table is not sorting. Please tell me solution

Answer (score 1):

As I Understood, **You need to sort an Array**. A table view is just UI. So before Assign a value to a Table view, you need to required to sort any array.

```
Proposed Steps:
1. Get data Assign In Array (Whatever data source)
2. Sort An Array
3. Reload Table View
```

**You can Sort ant array using below way**

```
struct Contact {
  var firstName: String
  var lastName: String
}

var contacts = [
  Contact(firstName: "Leonard", lastName: "Charleson"),
  Contact(firstName: "Michael", lastName: "Webb"),
  Contact(firstName: "Charles", lastName: "Alexson"),
  Contact(firstName: "Michael", lastName: "Elexson"),
  Contact(firstName: "Alex", lastName: "Elexson"),
]

contacts.sort {
  ($0.lastName, $0.firstName) <
    ($1.lastName, $1.firstName)
}

print(contacts)

// [
//   Contact(firstName: "Charles", lastName: "Alexson"),
//   Contact(firstName: "Leonard", lastName: "Charleson"),
//   Contact(firstName: "Alex", lastName: "Elexson"),
//   Contact(firstName: "Michael", lastName: "Elexson"),
//   Contact(firstName: "Michael", lastName: "Webb")
// ]
```

**OR**

```
var students = ["Kofi", "Abena", "Peter", "Kweku", "Akosua"]
students.sort()
print(students)
// Prints ["Abena", "Akosua", "Kofi", "Kweku", "Peter"]
```

**Formula For Sort an Array**

```
Swift 3:
let sortedNameAry = nameStrAry.sort { $0.nameStr < $1.nameStr }
For Swift 4 you can use only this
let sortedNameAry = nameStrAry.sorted(by: <)
```

Happy Coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in the code.

First of all use a struct

```
struct Student {
    let name : String
    let id : Int
}
```

Then declare two **native** arrays (never use `NSMutable..` collection types), one for the complete set of data and one for the filtered data

```
var students = [Student(name:"Rancho", id: 1437404654),
                Student(name:"Mastora", id: 1932617669),
                Student(name:"Amanda", id: 1457367179)]

var filteredStudents = [Student]()
```

In `textDidChange` check for empty string, filter the data and set `searchActive` accordingly.

And once again, prefer native filter API over Foundation `NSPredicate`

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        searchActive = false
        filteredStudents.removeAll()
    } else {
        filteredStudents = students.filter {$0.name.range(of: searchText, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil 
                                         || String($0.id).range(of: searchText) != nil }
        searchActive = true
    }
    resultTable.reloadData()
}
```

The filtered array is in the same order as the main array.

In the table view data source methods show the data depending on `searchActive`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searchActive ? filteredStudents.count : students.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell

    let student = searchActive ? filteredStudents[indexPath.row] : students[indexPath.row]      
    cell.idTextField.text = "\(student.id)"
    cell.nameTextField.text = student.name"

    return cell    
}
```